# how to parse ENCODED html within an XML document using XSLT

Tags: xslt, encoding, rss

I'm trying to parse Feedburner's full text RSS feed (for example http://feeds.feedburner.com/IeeeSpectrumFullText) and the HTML content is in an element called "content:encoded", but it is encoded (the < symbol becomes `&lt;` etc.).  I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to decode that content via an XSLT transformation.  I know that within PHP I can decode and parse it, but I'm hoping there's a way to do this purely in XSLT so that I can only have one PHP process (not conditionally decoding the HTML as necessary).

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: Your title says "how to parse encoded HTML", in your text you ask if it is possible "to decode" that content with XSLT. If all you need is writing the encoded HTML to the result then use `<xsl:value-of select="content:encoded" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>`. Parsing is difficult, if you want to parse the HTML into nodes to apply XPath or XSLT to parsed nodes then we need to know which XSLT processor and which XSLT version you use or can use.

Comment: @MartinHonnen: Actually, DOE isn't needed at all -- just use <xsl:output method="text"/>

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev, well, I suppose the element's content is to be output with some other HTML. But you are right, if only the content of those elements should be output, then using `output method="text"` suffices.